# Cauchy problem, partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

find the solution of the following partial differential equation

$xu_x + (x+y)u_y = u+1$

given that $u(x,0) = x^2$

I know that I will use the lagrange characteristic equation to obtain $\phi(x,y,u) = c_1$ and $\psi(x,y,u) = c_2$ then use $u(x,0) = x^2$ to combine $c_1$ and $c_2$. I have already obtained $\phi(x,y,u)$ as you can see in the image below but $\psi(x,y,u)$ is giving me trouble. Please help me out.

[how I obtained $\phi(x,y,u)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Gic.jpg)

Comment: You just need to solve $$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{x+y} \implies y' = \frac{y}{x} + 1 \implies \left( \frac{1}{x} y \right) ' = \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: I understood until hear                                                                                          $\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{x(1+\frac{y}{x})}$  which implies                                                        
$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 + \frac{y}{x}$                                                                            please help me with the last part. I didn't get it

Comment: $$\frac{dy}{x+y} = \frac{dx}{x} \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x+y}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$xu_x + (x+y)u_y = u+1$$
You correctly wrote the Charpit-Lagrange ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{x+y}=\frac{du}{u+1}$$
Also you correctly found a first characteristic equation in solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{u+1}$
$$\ln|x|-\ln|u+1|=C_1$$
or equivalently with $C_1=-\ln|c_1|$ :
$$\frac{u+1}{x}=c_1$$

One need at least one other characteristic equation. Why didn't you solve $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{x+y}$ ? This is a first order linear ODE : $y'=1+\frac{y}{x}$
$$\frac{1}{x}e^{y/x}=c_2$$

The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_1=F(c_2)$ is :

$$\frac{u+1}{x}=F\left(\frac{1}{x}e^{y/x} \right)$$

$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the specified condition).
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=-1+x\: F\left(\frac{1}{x}e^{y/x} \right)}$$

Condition : $$u(x,0)=x^2=-1+x\: F\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)$$
Let $X=\frac{1}{x}$
$$\frac{1}{X^2}=-1+\frac{1}{X}\: F\left(X\right)$$
$$F(X)=X+\frac{1}{X}$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is known. We put it into the above general solution where $X=\frac{1}{x}e^{y/x}$ :
$$u=-1+x\left(\frac{1}{x}e^{y/x}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}e^{y/x}} \right)$$
$$u(x,y)=-1+e^{y/x}+x^2e^{-y/x}$$

Comment: thank you so much I studied ordinary differential equations last year it has been some time. Thank you